# Unable to install software on Ubuntu 23:10, specically python pip

Tags: package-management, software-installation, python3, restricted

I tried using advice from other questions asked here. I ran:

```
python3 -m venv tutorial_env
source tutorial_env/bin/activate -y
```

in the terminal.

This is what the terminal displays after execution:

```
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not available.    
On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv package using the following command. 

    apt install python3.11-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.   
After installing the python3-venv package, recreate your virtual environment.  

Failing command: /home/user/tutorial_env/bin/python3

bash: tutorial_env/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

Then using the command `sudo apt install python3.11-venv -y`
results in `waiting for cache lock held by Ubuntu-restricted-extras process`.

In Software & Updates all options are enabled.

I also tried this command in terminal before the following commands: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` I verified that my python version is Python 3.11.6 using `python3 --version`.

Comment: What happens when you omit the automatic yes `-y` when trying to install `python3.11-venv` - what question(s) is it automatically answering yes to?

Comment: Karel you are right, omitting the -y worked. I thought the -y would be a short cut around the "do you wish to continue?", to which I simply typed y and enter.